# IBAction wont connect to my element

Tags: ios, uicontrol

Ive been trying to search online and in my "book" to found a conclusive answer, but haven't been able to. I am working with an UIImageView and want to connect it to an IBAction. When Ctrl-dragging to my correlating VC.m, it won't let me. I then tried to go under attributes inspector and tick the "User Interaction Enabled" checkbox, AND under the identity inspector I checked *traits* checkbox for Button. Shouldn't this make my element/control be able to connect to an action? Digging a little further I was reading about passive, active and static controls, but I got the notion that you should be able to connect an action to any control the user interacts with, since they all inherit from UIControl.

Any enlightenment very much appreciated.

(I also tried with a few other elements, but I seem to be able able to connect the action working with a button)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `UIImageView` does not inherit from `UIControl`. If you want to perform an action when the user touches your image then you will need to add a `UIGestureRecognizer` to it.

Comment: I did look into this, but thought connecting an IBAction would be easier (apparently not possible:))

Comment: I have 4 images. If I add a UIGestureRecognizer, how do I decide what image has been touched. Since the IBAction connected takes the gesture as parameter, I dont see that Im able to use the sender to decide what image has been touched. (I will probably use buttons instead, but Id very much like to know how to do this)

Comment: `UIGestureRecognizer` has a `tag` property that takes integer. Use different `UIGestureRecognizer` with same `IBAction` for each `UIImage` and give different tag value to each gesture. Then, in IBAction you can check the tag by using `if else` or by using `switch` statement that which image is tapped.

Answer (score 1):

First a couple of clarifications:

- Traits is used by accessibility only. It does not provide you with
  touch-detection
- User interaction enabled also does not mean what you
  think it means
  [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/)

I think you need some sort of UIGestureRecognizer or an UIButton

Comment: So pretty basically IBActions are only used for UIButtons? Could you elaborate just a tad more on the traits/accessibility part?

Comment: Well its all in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/reference/UIAccessibility_Protocol/index.html)
IBActions can be set on anything you can attach a UIGestureRecognizer on (as far as I know, any subclass of UIView is eligible)

Comment: Ah right, Ive only been working with gestures programmatically. I see I can add one in the IB from the objet list. That would make me eligible to connect an IBActtion I suppose

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to get a UIImageView to act like a UIButton. Why don't you simply replace the UIImageView with a UIButton and set the button's background image to the same image you were using for the imageView? Then hook the button up to the IBAction. A button is an active control - it is designed to do exactly what you want, so why not use it?